# unable to insert data into hbase using apache flume

Tags: hadoop, hbase, flume

i m using flume to insert log file data to hbase table.but nothing is inserted into table.
flume agent is as follows:

```
 agent1.sources = tail
 agent1.channels = memoryChannel
 agent1.sinks = loggerSink sink1
 agent1.sources.tail.type = exec
agent1.sources.tail.command = tail -f /usr/local/jarsfortest/LogsForTest/generatingLogs-app.logs
agent1.sources.tail.channels = memoryChannel

agent1.sinks.loggerSink.channel = memoryChannel
agent1.sinks.loggerSink.type = logger

agent1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = memoryChannel
agent1.sinks.sink1.table = testFlume
agent1.sinks.sink1.columnFamily = log
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer
#agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.regex = [a-zA-Z0-9]*[^C][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^C][a-zA-Z0-9]*
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.regex =[a-zA-Z0-9]*^C[a-zA-Z0-9]*^C[a-zA-Z0-9]*
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.colNames = id, no_fill_reason, bid

agent1.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent1.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 1000
```

above agent is started successfully..but log file data does not inserted into hbase.
log file data is as below:
id0^COK^C10
i.e. data is control char seperated.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error message or does it fail just silently?

Comment: no error message..sink started successfully..but there is no data in table..

Answer (score 0):

reason may be regexpression is not matching
to debug this follow the below steps

1) use to start only one agent with this option

```
flume-ng agent -n $1 -c ../../config/conf/ -f ../../config/conf/$1.conf -Xmx3g **-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket, address=1044,server=y,suspend=y**
  --classpath ../lib/*:../../config/conf/zoo.cfg:../.
```

once you start the script

> listening to 1044...

message will come.

2) create eclipse remote application to connect to your server name  and port as 1044

3) `getActions` method is responsible for putting the rows in to hbase..

Put a break point in `getActions` method of `EventSerializer`

```
public List<Row> getActions() throws FlumeException {
        List actions = Lists.newArrayList();

        Matcher m = this.inputPattern.matcher(new String(this.payload, this.charset));
        if (!(m.matches())) {
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }

        if (m.groupCount() != this.colNames.size())
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        try {
            byte[] rowKey;
            byte[] rowKey;
            if (this.rowKeyIndex < 0)
                rowKey = getRowKey();
            else {
                rowKey = m.group(this.rowKeyIndex + 1).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
            }
            Put put = new Put(rowKey);

            for (int i = 0; i < this.colNames.size(); ++i) {
                if (i != this.rowKeyIndex) {
                    put.add(this.cf, (byte[]) this.colNames.get(i), m.group(i + 1).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
                }
            }
            if (this.depositHeaders) {
                for (Map.Entry entry : this.headers.entrySet()) {
                    put.add(this.cf, ((String) entry.getKey()).getBytes(this.charset),
                                    ((String) entry.getValue()).getBytes(this.charset));
                }
            }
            actions.add(put);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FlumeException("Could not get row key!", e);
        }
        return actions;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help on the analysis of root cause.

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate `this flume-ng process`.

Watch the output carefully. 
There will be three type of Metrics:

- Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE
- Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL
- Shutdown Metric for type: SINK

For example:

```
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. source.start.time == 1483838106878
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. source.stop.time == 1483838118766
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.append-batch.accepted == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.append-batch.received == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.append.accepted == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.append.received == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.events.accepted == 141
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.events.received == 147
Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: r1. src.open-connection.count == 0

Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.start.time == 1483838106874
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.stop.time == 1483838118789
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.capacity == 1000000
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.current.size == 141
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.event.put.attempt == 147
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.event.put.success == 141
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.event.take.attempt == 31
Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: c1. channel.event.take.success == 26

Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.start.time == 1483838108891
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.stop.time == 1483838118758
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.batch.complete == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.batch.empty == 4
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.batch.underflow == 1
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.connection.closed.count == 1
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.connection.creation.count == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.connection.failed.count == 0
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.event.drain.attempt == 26
Shutdown Metric for type: SINK, name: k1. sink.event.drain.sucess == 0
```

In the above example, the issue is during the sink stage because of the `drain.success` is equal to 0.